# Avoid code duplication on child classes of an abstract class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, abstract-class

I'm working on an old Struts application which has an abstract action to create Excel exports by filling Excel template files.

Each Excel export action extends this parent class and adds its own implementation for filling the Excel template and defines its own template and output filename.

```
public abstract class ExcelExportAction extends BaseAction {
    protected abstract String getInputFilename();
    protected abstract String getOutputFilename();
    protected abstract HSSFWorkbook modifyWorkbook(HSSFWorkbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request);

    @Override
    protected final ActionForward run(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

        Workbook workbook = new Workbook(getInputFilename());
        workbook = modifyWorkbook(workbook, request);
        addWorkBookToResponse(workbook, getOutputFilename());       

        return null;
    }
...
}
```

Implementations are looking like this and this is where the code duplication is "warned" by SonarQube:

```
public class BudgetReportExcelAction extends ExcelExportAction {
    private static final String INPUT_FILENAME = "Report-Budget-Template.xls";
    private static final String OUTPUT_FILENAME = "Report-Customerbudget.xls";

    @Override
    protected String getInputFilename() {
        return INPUT_FILENAME;
    }
    @Override
    protected String getOutputFilename() {
        return OUTPUT_FILENAME;
    }
    @Override
    protected HSSFWorkbook modifyWorkbook(HSSFWorkbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request) {
        /* modify the workbook */
        return workbook;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to avoid the duplication?

Comment: You could create some kind of `DefaultExcelAction` that extends `ExcelExport` and implements the common functionality, then have `BudgetReportExcelAction` (and the other child classes) extend `DefaultExcelAction` instead of `ExcelExport`.

Comment: Well I don't see any duplication here ... yes you have to override over an over the methods, but that's the point of OOP.

Comment: SonarQube does, but as stated in other comments this is probably kind of paranoid configuration...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is hardly any code duplication in the code that I see here, but if you really want to "squeeze water from a stone", you can add a constructor to the base class, which accepts the input-filename and output-filename, and make each derived class pass its input-filename and output-filename to the constructor of the base class.

Comment: I can't take the constructor way here because of the fact that these are Struts actions and as far as I know they need to have an empty constructor.

Comment: Well then, you are stuck with invoking overridables.  I do not think it is a big deal.  We tend to start talking about code duplication from several non-trivial lines and above. If it is in fact as you say with struts, then for me, that would be enough reason to never use struts and not work for anyone who requires working with struts.

Comment: You beat me by one minute; but you get my upvote ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A non-answer here: there is no "code duplication" in your examples.

The point is: your abstract class *drives* a certain "layout" for your child class; but that is the **essence** of using an abstract class.

In other words: nothing to worry about here.

You are following well known, "approved" patterns; for example by nicely using the @Override annotation in your child class.

All fine, have a nice day!

Comment: Ok, it's just about that SonarQube which tells me there is duplicated code all over. Have to ignore it this time, I think... Thx!

Comment: Someone has configured your SonarQube to be paranoid about code duplication.

Comment: C-:= taken care of.

Comment: There we go ;-)